# python time stamp convert to datetime without a year specified

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a csv file of a years worth of time series data where the time stamp looks like the code insert below. One thing to mention about the data its a *30 year averaged hourly weather data, so there isnt a year specified* with the time stamp.

```
Date
01-01T01:00:00
01-01T02:00:00
01-01T03:00:00
01-01T04:00:00
01-01T05:00:00
01-01T06:00:00
01-01T07:00:00
01-01T08:00:00
01-01T09:00:00
01-01T10:00:00
01-01T11:00:00
01-01T12:00:00
01-01T13:00:00
01-01T14:00:00
01-01T15:00:00
01-01T16:00:00
01-01T17:00:00
01-01T18:00:00
01-01T19:00:00
01-01T20:00:00
01-01T21:00:00
01-01T22:00:00
01-01T23:00:00
```

I can read the csv file just fine:

`df = pd.read_csv('weather_cleaned.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)`

If I do a `pd.to_datetime(df)` this will error out:
`ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing`

Would anyone have any tips to convert my df to datetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `date_parser` argument ([check docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)), e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('weather_cleaned.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'], 
                  date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%mT%H:%M:%S'))
print(df.head())
```

output

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1900-01-01 01:00:00, 1900-01-01 02:00:00, 1900-01-01 03:00:00, 1900-01-01 04:00:00, 1900-01-01 05:00:00]
```

of course you can define different function, maybe specify different year, etc..
e.g. if you want year 2020 instead of 1900 use

`date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d-%mT%H:%M:%S').replace(year=2020)`

Note **I assume it's day-month format, change format string accordingly**.

EDIT: Change my example to reflect that Date column should be used as index.

Comment: Hi, would you know how to get around with? `ValueError: time data '01-13T00:00:00' does not match format '%d-%mT%H:%M:%S'`

Comment: read my note - I assume day-month format. change the format string to `'%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'`

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to append a default year:

```
 pd.to_datetime('2020-' + df['Date'])
```